# Adding GET params in url php

Tags: php

I am trying to add `params` to a `url` but `"&"` is appearing twice.

it shows: `"/getAllBrands?&key1=2&key2=1&limit=1"`

I want it to be like this: `"/getAllBrands?key1=2&limit=1"`

```php
url = sprintf("/%s?", $apiMethod);
$pos = strpos($url, "?");
foreach ($params[0] as $key => $value) {

    if ($pos) {
        $url .= "&";
    }
    $url .= sprintf('%s=%s', $key, urlencode($value));
}
```

Would appreciate if someone could help, thank you.

Comment: just simply use `http_build_query` and save yourself with that hibbyjibby string manipulation

Comment: PHP has a great function available to build HTTP parameters called [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: @Ghost I was gonna say the same thing! lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just doing this:

```
 $url .= http_build_query($params);
```

or

```
 $url .= http_build_query($params[0]);
```

Not sure exactly how $params is... but you should get the point.

Here's the docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: Worked fine, thanks v much. Used the second option :)